# Proof of limit when multiplying with function with a limit of 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let f and g be defined on A ⊆ R to R, and let c be a cluster point of A. Suppose f is bounded on a neighborhood of c and that $\lim_{x \to c} g$ = 0. Prove that $\lim_{x \to c} fg$ = 0.

Comment: Well, if $lim_{x \to c} g = 0$, then surely there's a neighborhood of $c$ over which $|g| \leq 1$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hace that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}g(x)=0$ and there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for $x \in V(c)$ ($V(c)$ denotates a neighborhood of $c$). So $$0\leq \lim_{x \to c} |f(x)g(x)|\leq M\lim_{x \to c} |g(x)|=M\cdot 0=0.$$ Hence, by the squeeze theorem, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}(fg)(x)=0$.

Comment: Curious question: when would M > $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
for $x$ in a neighborhood of $c$ we have

$|fg(x)|=|f(x)g(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in V}f \cdot |g(x)|$

where $V$ is the neighborhood of $c$.

In particular, if $x$ is sufficiently close to $c$ then $|g(x)|$ is sufficiently close to zero, and $\sup_{x\in A} f$ is a constant.